# Site Collection Features link is missing under Site Collection Administration

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am at the root site and got SCA permissions. This site was recently migrated from SP2010 to SP2013. I could access the page directly _layouts/15/managefeatures.aspx?Scope=Site

Any ideas why the Site Collection Features link is missing from Site Settings page?

Answer (score 0):

Whether this issue occurred in another web applications? You can create a new one to check.

Is there any other links which is missing in the site settings?

Try to [clear the configuration cache](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-2010-2013-21f55320) and clear the browser cache and check again.

In the _layouts/15/managefeatures.aspx?Scope=Site page, make sure the “SharePoint Server Standard site collection features” is activated.

Comment: This issue occurred only on a particular web application. Its fine on other  web applications.  There are other links also missing. I've activated the features but still no difference